# How can I browse the tree structure of an existing SVN repo in a web browser?

Tags: svn

I only have read/write admission to an existing Subversion repository, and I don't have any access to the server. I was wondering if I could install some software that enable me to browse the tree structure of an existing subversion repo in a web browser?

I took a look at WebSVN, unfortunately since I don't have control over the server so I couldn't use WebSVN.

Thanks very much for your input!

Comment: If you can't install a repository browser web app on the server, there's no way to do this in a web browser.

Comment: Why do you need to browse in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is served via http or https, you can simply point your web browser to the repository url, and it will show you the latest revision.

If it isn't, you may be able to install a web viewer on another computer (e.g. your own) and configure it to display the remote repository.